# I don´t get any compiling errors even though there should be and I don´t think I can find a log file

Tags: texworks

I recently downloaded MikTeX and wrote my first file in TeXworks. I managed to turn it into a PDF, until I realized that part of the text was hanging out of a line (basically the classic overfull hbox error.) But shouldn´t there have been an error notice telling me this? I read in a manual that you could see the errors in a log file. I checked the folder where I had saved my file and there is a `file.pdf`, a `file.aux`, a file which is a TeX-document, something that says `file.synctex.gz(busy)` and a file which is a text document. Is any of these the log file? 
Did I maybe forget to download something...?

Comment: an overfull box is a warning not an error, you should have a `file.log` in the same directory as your source `file.tex` and the `file.aux` file. Probably the `.log` fiel is teh file you meant by "file that is a text document" ?

Comment: Thank you!Yes, I think that that might be the log-file. What´s the difference between a warning and an error? Warnings are meant to show up as well, aren´t they?

Comment: With an error then (by default) TeX stops and interacts with the user, so you can type `x` to quit `h` to get help etc. Some IDE always run tex in scrollmode so it doesn't stop, in which case warnings and errors are less different, but the format in the log is still different, errors start with `!` and warnings say `warning`

Comment: I don't have that editor but I would be very surprised if you have to look in the filesystem to find the log. Any tex-specific editor has a menu option to show the log after you have run latex.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thank you, that cleared up the warning-problem. Mine didn´t show me the log-file, but I´m pretty sure it´s the file that is a text document, so that´s fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, overfull boxes are only warnings, not errors. If there is a `*.synctex.gz(busy)` hanging around it is most likely from a previous compilation run that stopped with errors. Without `(busy)` at the end, this file is used to allow jumping back and forth between the source and the typeset PDF.

The `.log` file should be in the same folder as the `.tex` file you compiled, with the same base name. So if you compiled `file.tex`, after LaTeX runs, you should find `file.log` in the same directory.

But many editors with IDE-like features have built-in capability to view the log file and possibly step through any warnings/errors. TeXworks is one of these: you can go to

> Window → Show Console Output

or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> to toggle a pane at the bottom of the window. This shows you the log output right in the editor window. If there are any errors or warnings after compilation, another tab also appears in this area reporting the warnings/errors.